# Separation by density

Tags: density

How can i separate water vapour from a mixture of gases given that water vapour has a lower density than the gases?

I am doing an experiment on separating water vapour from exhaust gases. I have not tried anything yet. I am not sure on how to get started.

Comment: It will be far more practical and efficient to condense the water by cooling the gas mixture.

Answer (score 0):

Cool the mixture to condense the water or absorb the water in (say) dry Calcium Chloride.

Answer (score 0):

You can check fractional distillation which is used to separate mixture with components having different boiling points which is true in your case.